# How to test feature toggle with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I want to test a feature toggle with Spock. It is a very simple implementation.

**application.yml**

```
feature:
  toggles:
    checksLoginAndRegistration: true
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Value("${feature.toggles.checksLoginAndRegistration}")
private boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;
    
private void validateLicense(LicenseData licenseData,RegistrationData registrationData) {
        validateAddress(registrationData, UserRepository::logWarning);
        if(checksLoginAndRegistration) {
            try {
                service.validateRegistration(registrationData);
            } catch (RgValidationException rgValidationException) {
                throw new AccountRegulationBlockedException(registrationData.username());
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to test toggle that I have made. Because if it's true my previous implemented tests are passing, if it's not, they will fail.

For example, this is one of the tests that fails if `checksLoginAndRegistration=fale`

```
@Test(expected = UserRepository.AccountBlockedException.class)
    public void createShouldFailWhenAccountIsBlocked() {
        doThrow(newUserRepository.AccountBlockedException(this.user.username))
                .when(service).validateRegistration(any());

        when(client.call(anyString(), any(), any(ObjectNode.class)))
                .thenReturn(Observable.just(new Reply(objectMapper.createArrayNode(),
                        objectMapper.createObjectNode().put("userID", "id").put("verificationCode", "emCode"))));
        when(repository.userService.findUserByMobileNumber(any(PhoneNumber.class))).thenReturn(Stream.empty());
        when(countryRepository.findByCode(any())).thenReturn(COUNTRY_DEFAULT);
        repository.create(RegistrationData.builder().withUser(this.userDE)
                .addCredential(new PasswordCredential("pass"))
                .withAffiliateId("affId")
                .withValidationType(email)
                .withLicenseData(new DELicenseData("bName", "bPlace", "DE", "BE"))
                .build(), anonymousInfo, "https://test");
    }
```

What do I need to add in my existing test to test feature toggle, or do I need create new test for it?

Comment: That test isn't spock...  Do you have the spock test that isn't working?

Comment: Ooooh sh...t man sorry completely wrote wrong. Too many things on my mind. Yes, no it's mockito.

Comment: No worries we've all been there 

Comment: Why not just create a setter for `checksLoginAndRegistration` then set it to whatever value you want in your test?

Comment: Yes, maybe that also. Can you please write it as code example?